# Github history for pull request sometimes includes previously merged commits

Tags: git, github

For some of my private repos, when I commit a new PR from `origin` (me) to `upstream` (main repo), the PR includes my current commits, but also previous commits from previous PRs.

Every time I do some new work, I do the following:

(on `localhost`)

- switch to `master`
- pull down `upstream/master` to localhost `master`
- create a new branch eg. `feature/blah` or `bug/blah`.
- do work / commit or make multi-commits.
- push to `origin`
- PR from `origin/my branch` up to `upstream/master`
- review PR. accept and **squash-merge**.

it's like .. somewhere at some point, something didn't realise that the previous commits were actually merged/accept ... and as such, keeps thinking I need to push those up.

What's even weirder is that the **files changes are ONLY those files in the commits I did in this branch** ... and not the files that were changed in the previous commits, which are listed in the commit history.

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: Are you checking the delete-branch-after-merge checkbox any time you merge? If not, could it be that the branch you're merging isn't new, it (coincidentally) has the same name as a branch you used a year ago?

Comment: I usually delete the branch in github (manually) and locally. In fact, I deleted the entire folder locally, cloned `origin` and did my stuff (in a new branch) and then pushed the commits up to `origin`. Made PR and blamo -> we have the above picture.

Comment: I meant: is the name of the branch you're creating the same as a branch that used to be on origin? I'm wondering if what  you're seeing can be explained by an old branch on origin being recreated.

Comment: When i create a new `origin:branch` it's 99.9999% a totally new name.

Comment: Ah. Sorry then, that was my only theory.

Comment: We have a small team with several private repos and have the exact same problem.  The PR branch names are all based on github issue numbers and thus unique.  I suspect this might have something to do with squashing commits as the problem started when this option became available for PRs on github.com.  I have also tried rebasing and fast-forwarding to no avail.  There are several pending SO posts with similar characteristics, so this is a real issue and we need a git expert to hopefully comment.